# Apply product offer when subtotal grater or equal 1000 only for specific date

Tags: product, event-observer, magento2.2.6

I want to add new product offer when cart subtotal >= 1000

This offer valid only for every month between day 1 to 7 (1-m-yyyy to 7-m-yyyy).

Therefore i used below event -

```
<event name="checkout_cart_save_after">
        <observer name="after_upfate_to_cart" instance="myvendor\mymodule\Observer\Updatetocart" />
    </event>
```

this event **checkout_cart_save_after**  only working when user doing any changes on cart(add,update,delete).

**issue ->** user can buy product offer using below activity -

user added offer on offer dates but buy when expired offer date without changes on cart.

stop this activity i did below two event -

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch_onestepcheckout_index_index">
        <observer name="mymodule_before_checkout_page" instance="myvendor\mymodule\Observer\BeforeQuoteLoad" />
    </event>
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index">
        <observer name="mymodule_before_cart_page" instance="myvendor\mymodule\Observer\BeforeQuoteLoad" />
    </event>
```

**Anyone have best idea of this activity??**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: anyone need more explanation ??